# How to design an application keeping SOLID principles and Design Patterns in mind

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, rspec, cucumber, solid-principles

Say an application in ruby when started has two modes : commandline mode and filemode

When given a parameter **ruby myprogram input.txt output.txt**, it generates an output based on some commands in input file. also when not provided with any parameter it presents us with a command prompt. with following commands.

```
create_class_with_capacity 40

create_student_with_marks Alex 70

create_student_with_marks Mathew 30

create_student_with_marks John 55

..

create_student_with_marks Sylvia 70 etc...


fail_student_roll_no 12

=> Student with roll number 12 #{student} failed


give_marks_to_roll_no 70 1

=>Student with roll number 1 Alex got 70 marks


find_all_students_with_marks 70

=> Alex, Peter , Russell , Mark etc...
```

How to design such an application keeping RSpec,TDD , Cucumber , SOLID and Patterns in Mind.
What i am directly asking is What should be Objects here to design what should be a module if applicable etc.. ? and how to gauge what needs to be tested here and what not ? Designing the most Appropriate Mechanism in terms of Object Oriented design.

Also Please Refer To some books or blogs to learn these kind of object oriented design principles and practices for ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying that you have to write this application?  Is this homework?

Sounds to me like you're suffering from analysis paralysis.  There are far too many buzzwords zooming around in your head.

Stop worrying about patterns and what not.  Decompose the problem into pieces and start writing some code.

The one recommendation I'd make is to keep I/O out of our classes.  Put all the logic that has nothing to do with interacting with users in the base classes.  That way they'll still work if you're asked to create a web-based UI to replace your text version.

What has to be tested?  All the code that you think might break.

The most appropriate method of object-oriented design?  Do the obvious thing: nouns are potential objects in your problem statement, verbs are potential methods.

Here are some potential objects that I see: Student, Course, Roll.

Here are some potential methods: CRUD operations for Student and Course; setting grades and marking a Student as failing.

It's not that complicated.  Think "simple" and get something working, then refine it.

UPDATE:

It'd be easier to answer you if you could describe what you did.

If it's the homework problem that I think it is, I doubt that it would make much difference.  Rather than make us guess, why don't you read SOLID and start looking at the classes you created ask yourself if it conforms to those principles.

Patterns?  Overrated.  Don't worry about them.

Comment: I have already written this application but probably it wasn't right in terms of Design principles, I am just looking for a clue as to how to design this in a more OOP Fashion and Following SOLID Principles and writing tests. It was really difficult to gauge what to test and what not, and what patterns to follow. What to make as objects , what a singleton etc ...

Comment: No it was a problem asked in a pre Job interview problem set.

UPDATE: OK what i did was, that at run time i detected whether ARGV is supplied or not, then i made a module which had all the commands that needed to be implemented as methods say :

    create_class_with_capacity 40

This is a method with students as parameter,

when in interactive mode i eval the input given to a REPL loop and in file mode i read all commands in an array and eval the commands individually.

Comment: The module was called individually in two classes called Interactive and Filemode in whichever case. so all command became instance method for a given scenario. Also each student were a open struct inside a hash. Struct was chosen for convenience like **@student.marks , @student.status , @student.subjects** etc...

Comment: Sounds like you did just fine.  Did you get the interview?  An offer?  That's what matters here.

Comment: No I did not get any reply, Thats Why I started to think that may be something is wrong. And I needed to know What.

Comment: This is one that you have to figure out for yourself.  This isn't the best forum for learning what you could or could not have done.