# What does it mean when someone says that the module has both behavior and state?

Tags: ruby, oop, object, behavior

As I understand I got a code review that my module has behavior and state at the same time, what does it mean anyway ?

Isn't that the whole point of object oriented programming, that instead of operating on data directly with logical circuitry using functions. We choose to operate on these closed black-boxes (encapsulation) using a set of neatly designed keys, switches and gears.

Wouldn't such a scheme naturally contain data(state) and logic(behavior) at the same time ?

By module I mean : a real Ruby module.

I designed something like this : [How to design an application keeping SOLID principles and Design Patterns in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286205/how-to-design-an-application-keeping-solid-principles-and-design-patterns-in-min)

and implemented the commands in a module which I used to mixin.

Comment: Are you talking about 'module' in the ruby sense, or 'module' in the programming sense?

Comment: yes module as in real ruby module. i.e 

module student
def name
end
end

Comment: it's difficult to say anything without seeing the code of that module. I guess the reviewer expected the ideal of a Ruby module having behavior with no or little state.

Comment: Sorry cant show the code, but i am just saying cant there be a thumb rule ? that can we have state and behavior together or not in a module. but please take a look at the link in updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you are referring to, be it an object defined by a class (or type), a module, or anything else with code in it, ***state*** is data that is persisted over multiple calls to the thing.  If it "remembers" anything between one execution and the next, then it has state.

***Behavior***, otoh, is code that manipulates or processes that state-data, or non-state data that is used only during a single execution of the code, (like parameter values passed to a function). Methods, subroutines or functions, anything that changes or does something is *behavior*.

Most classes, types, or whatever,  have both data (state) and behavior, but....

Some classes or types are designed simply to carry data around. They are referred to as Data Transfer objects or DTOs, or Plain Old Container Objects (POCOs).  They only have state, and, generally, have little or no behavior.

Other times, a class or type is constructed to hold general utility functions, (like a Math Library). It will not maintain or keep any state between the many times it is called to perform one of its utilities.  The only data used in it is data passed in as parameters for each call to the library function, and that data is discarded when the routine is finished.  It has behavior. but no state.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in your thinking that OOP encapsulates the ideas of both behaviour and state and mixes the two things together, but from the wording of your question, I'm wondering if you have written a ruby module (mixin, whatever you want to call it) that is stateful, such that there is the potential for state leakage across multiple uses of the same module.

Without seeing the code in question I can't really give you a full answer.

Comment: Sorry cant show you the code as it is a interview question i promised not to leak.

Answer (score 0):

In Object-Oriented terminology, an object is said to have state when it encapsulates data (attributes, properties) and is said to have behavior when it offers operations (methods, procedures, functions) that operate (create, delete, modify, make calculations) on the data.

The same concepts can be extrapolated to a ruby module, it has "state" if it defined data accessible within the module, and it has "behavior" in the form of operations provided which operate on the data.